# How can I determine which function is responsible for calling a function listed by %prun?

Tags: python, optimization, ipython

I'm currently trying to optimize a bit of code using ipython's `%prun` magic.  Here is the output of both `%prun` and `%timeit` below:

```
In [5]: %prun hogopt.findHOGFeatures(lenna)
         260114 function calls in 5.614 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    5.529    5.529    5.613    5.613 hogopt.py:5(findHOGFeatures)
   260100    0.066    0.000    0.066    0.000 {math.floor}
        2    0.017    0.009    0.017    0.009 {cv2.Sobel}
        1    0.001    0.001    5.614    5.614 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {cv2.cv.GetMat}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 ImageClass.py:1977(getNumpyCv2)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.zeros}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageClass.py:1804(getMatrix)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'transpose' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageClass.py:1769(getBitmap)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}


In [6]: %timeit hogopt.findHOGFeatures(lenna)
1 loops, best of 3: 5.25 s per loop
```

**My question is as follows:**

It appears as though `math.floor` is responsible for the large majority of the execution time, but I'm wondering who is calling it, since it's never explicitly called in my code.  Is there a way to obtain this information?

Below is the full function definition, in case it can provide some insight.  Note that this function requires `SimpleCV` if you actually want to run it:

```
from itertools import product


def findHOGFeatures(img, n_divs=6, n_bins=6):
    """
    **SUMMARY**
    Get HOG(Histogram of Oriented Gradients) features from the image.


    **PARAMETERS**
    * *img* * - SimpleCV image
    * *n_divs* - the number of divisions(cells).
    * *n_divs* - the number of orientation bins.

    **RETURNS**
    Returns the HOG vector in a numpy array

    """
    # Size of HOG vector
    n_HOG = n_divs * n_divs * n_bins

    # Initialize output HOG vector
    HOG = np.zeros((n_HOG, 1))
    # Apply sobel on image to find x and y orientations of the image
    Icv = img.getNumpyCv2()
    Ix = cv2.Sobel(Icv, ddepth=cv.CV_32F, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=3)
    Iy = cv2.Sobel(Icv, ddepth=cv.CV_32F, dx=0, dy=1, ksize=3)

    Ix = Ix.transpose(1, 0, 2)
    Iy = Iy.transpose(1, 0, 2)
    cellx = img.width / n_divs  # width of each cell(division)
    celly = img.height / n_divs  # height of each cell(division)

    img_area = img.height * img.width  # Area of image

    BIN_RANGE = (2 * pi) / n_bins  # Range of each bin

    angles = np.arctan2(Iy, Ix)
    magnit = ((Ix ** 2) + (Iy ** 2)) ** 0.5
    it = product(xrange(n_divs), xrange(n_divs), xrange(cellx), xrange(celly))
    for m, n, i, j in it:
        # grad value
        grad = magnit[m * cellx + i, n * celly + j][0]
        # normalized grad value
        norm_grad = grad / img_area
        # Orientation Angle
        angle = angles[m*cellx + i, n*celly+j][0]
        # (-pi,pi) to (0, 2*pi)
        if angle < 0:
            angle += 2 * pi
        nth_bin = floor(float(angle/BIN_RANGE))
        HOG[((m * n_divs + n) * n_bins + int(nth_bin))] += norm_grad

    return HOG.transpose()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you appear to be calling `math.floor`:

```
nth_bin = floor(float(angle/BIN_RANGE))
```

Anyway, these calls only cost you 0.066 seconds over a total runtime of 5+ seconds. Your time seems to be spent in your loop. Probably because it is being executed 260100 times (as floor is called in your loop, and there are 260100 recorded calls to it).

Comment: Yikes, right you are.  This is largely copied-and-pasted, so clearly I missed that important detail -- and now I feel rather silly.  Thanks!